# I can't see my data stored in a LVM via SAMBA

Tags: linux, samba, lvm

I have merged several disks using LVM and I mount the volume in /home/user/Data. The system is Ubuntu server 18.04.02 64bit.

I've then shared /home/user/Data via Samba.

Finally I'm accessing the share via my Windows 10 desktop. I can see the Data folder, but inside it's completely empty.

Is there a way to show my data? Is there a specific reason why SAMBA can't display this data?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include your `smb.conf` file.

Comment: Hi Issam, since you solved you problem you might add the solution as answer and accept it, or just delete your question. It's up to you to decide how useful this might be for other users with the same problem.

Comment: Sure, I'll add a new reply. I'll wait 3 hours before accepting it (as apparently I can't do it now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this. Use a

´chmod 777 /path/to/folder`

It's not the best solution but it works. Bottom line: it was a permission issue.